# Publish docker-compose ephemeral port with ip address

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose you can specify ports like `1234` in order to publish it on an ephemeral port, and like `127.0.0.1:1234:1234` to publish it on a specific interface.

However, is there a way to use an ephemeral port on a specific interface?

There appears to be no `--ip` option to `docker-compose up` like there is for `docker run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless i am mistaken I assume you want to publish on a specific interface with ephemeral port - in a random way - you can use this in your docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1::1234"
```

Or if you don't need to specify an interface and just want an ephemeral port you can use this:

```
ports:
  - "1234"
```

In both scenarios this makes the container listen on a random port mapped to a specific port (e.g. `1234`) inside the container similar to what `-P` would do in `docker run`

To set an ip for container in docker-compose you can use the following to make it work similar to `--ip` in `docker run`, assuming you have a custom network called `my_network`

```
networks:
  my_network:
    ipv4_address: 172.20.1.5
```